# My VBA code worked in excel 2010 but does not in excel 2019

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2019

I have a code (seen below at the bottom of this message) built by someone else and it has worked very well in excel 2010 but our administration migrated us to excel 2019.  Now the same code produces errors.  I have also tried checking if there were new add-ins or references in the reference library in vba but have not found anything that removes the errors or allows the code to execute properly.

The function of the code is basically like this:

The code is linked to a pivot table in a worksheet in a workbook.  It will ask the user a few questions such as is this a 'RFQ' and then a msg box will open for them to enter a file name.  It then asks the user if they wish to have the data added to another worksheet in the same workbook.  After all these are answered the code should open an new workbook and copy/paste over data from a hidden worksheet from the original workbook into this new workbook.  This new workbook should become the focus and allow the user to make any other changes before they save and close it.

The code automatically saved the new workbook in a location (using a HLink) that is referenced from a cell on another hidden worksheet in the original workbook.

The errors that take place now is this: "The following features cannot be saved in macro-free workbooks: VB Project To save a file with these features, click No, and then choose a macro-enabled file type in the File type list. To continue saving as a macro-free workbook, click Yes.

If the user says yes, the it says the new workbook that was just created 'already exists in this location. Do you want to replace it?"

If you say yes, everything goes blank and you have to restart excel. If you say no, the vba debugger opens to the end of the code highlighting the last part of the code:

`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=HLink _ , FileFormat:"xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False`

I have tried changing some sections of the code. From this:

```
`'Save
On Error GoTo ErrFileClose:
HLink = (FilePath & "\" & FileName & "_" & Format(Date, "[$-409]yyyy-mm-d;@") & ".xlsx")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=HLink _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
End If`
```

To this:

```
'Save
On Error GoTo ErrFileClose:
HLink = (FilePath & "\" & FileName & "_" & Format(Date, "[$-409]yyyy-mm-d;@"))
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=HLink _
    , FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False
End If
```

And similarly, from this:

```
'Check if previously created file is open and close it so new one can be saved
    ErrFileClose:
        FinalFileName = FileName & "_" & Format(Date, "[$-409]yyyy-mm-d;@") & ".xlsx"
        Workbooks(FinalFileName).Close SaveChanges:=True
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=HLink _
           , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

To this:

```
   'Check if previously created file is open and close it so new one can be saved
ErrFileClose:
    FinalFileName = FileName & "_" & Format(Date, "[$-409]yyyy-mm-d;@")
    Workbooks(FinalFileName).Close SaveChanges:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=HLink _
        , FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False
```

These changes sometimes help and seem to remove the vb project error but it is not consistent every time I run the macro.
Any help is appreciated as we cannot move forward using this as it stands.
Thanks.

```
Sub ImportFile()
'
' ImportFile Macro

Call UnprotectAll

'Create Import
    Dim curWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim ReqType As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FinalFileName As String
    Dim FilePath As String
    FilePath = Sheets("X").Range("C3").Value
    Dim HLink As String
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Sheets("Import").Visible = True
    Sheets("Import").Copy
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
'Edit import to remove formulas and blank rows
    Range("A1:AC500").Value = Range("A1:AC500").Value
    Columns("C:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    Set curWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Windows("Transactions.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Import").Visible = False
    curWorkbook.Activate
    
'Save Import
    
    ReqType = MsgBox("Click YES if you are creating an RFQ", vbYesNoCancel)
    'vbCancel = 2, vbYes = 6, vbNo = 7
        If ReqType = 6 Then
            ReqType = "RFQ"
        Else
            If ReqType = 7 Then
                ReqType = "Ordered"
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    FileName = InputBox("Please enter the Incident number or other Unique ID Number to save this file as:")
    
'Cancel Save
    If FileName = "" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Call ProtectAll
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        MsgBox ("File Not Created")
        Exit Sub
    Else
    
'Save
    On Error GoTo ErrFileClose:
    HLink = (FilePath & "\" & FileName & "_" & Format(Date, "[$-409]yyyy-mm-d;@") & ".xlsx")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=HLink _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    End If

'Add Order to Receive tab ?
    If MsgBox("Ok to add this data as Transaction: " & ReqType & "?", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then
    Windows("Transactions.xlsm").Activate
    Else
    
'Do Not add Order to transactions Order - Receipt
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Call ProtectAll
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        MsgBox ("This has not been added as a transaction. Click the HuB button when ready to try again.  A new import file will be created and can be saved over the one just created.")
    Exit Sub
    End If

'AddOrder to Transactions Order - Receipt
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ToBeOrderedPivot").RowRange.Select
    
'Remove headers and column 1
    Selection.Offset(1, 1).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1, _
    Selection.Columns.Count).Select

'Remove Extra Columns
    Dim FirstRow As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    
    FirstRow = Selection.Row
    LastRow = FirstRow + Selection.Rows.Count - 1
    Range("C" & FirstRow & ":F" & LastRow & ",AA" & FirstRow & ":AA" & LastRow & ",L" & FirstRow & ":L" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    
'Move to end of Orders  table
    Sheets("Receive").Select
    Count = Range("Orders[Mtl ID]").Rows.Count
    Range("B" & Count + 4).Select
    
'Paste Values
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
'Set Values
    
    Selection.Offset(0, 8).Columns(1).Value = Selection.Offset(0, 2).Columns(1).Value
    If ReqType = "RFQ" Then
    Selection.Offset(0, 2).Columns(1).Value = 0
    Selection.Offset(0, 7).Columns(1).Value = ReqType
    Else: Selection.Offset(0, 2).Columns(1).Value = Selection.Offset(0, 5).Columns(1).Value
    End If
    Selection.Offset(0, 5).Columns(1).Value = Selection.Offset(0, 3).Columns(1).Value
    Selection.Offset(0, 3).Columns(1).Value = Selection.Offset(0, 4).Columns(1).Value
    Selection.Offset(0, 4).Columns(1).Value = Selection.Offset(0, 8).Columns(1).Value
    Selection.Offset(0, 8).Columns(1).Value = FileName
    Selection.Offset(0, 9).Columns(1).Value = Format(Date, "[$-409]yyyy-mm-d;@")
    
    
    
        
 'Sort Table
    Call SortReceive
    Call ProtectAll
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
'Return to Import File
    curWorkbook.Activate
    
Exit Sub

'Check if previously created file is open and close it so new one can be saved
ErrFileClose:
    FinalFileName = FileName & "_" & Format(Date, "[$-409]yyyy-mm-d;@") & ".xlsx"
    Workbooks(FinalFileName).Close SaveChanges:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=HLink _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    Resume Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm thinking that it's an `ActiveWorkbook` problem.  I'm not sure so not adding as an answer, but when it asks about overwriting does the file flick back to the one that contains the code?  Clicking 'yes' will then try and save the Active file which is now the one running the code and possibly causing a crash.  This looks like a prime example of why `Select` and `Active` should be avoided.  Have a look at this: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10717999#10717999).

Comment: Let me look at the reference you supplied and see if I can try some sample changes to see how it reacts.

Comment: Darren, I looked at the site you mentioned and I am not a coder but will try to apply this later to clean up the code.  With the assistance of others I changed the code under the 'AddOrder to Transactions Order-Receipt to `Worksheets("Order").Activate
    'Activesheets.PivotTables("ToBeOrderedPivot").RowRange.Select
    Sheets("Order").PivotTables("ToBeOrderedPivot").RowRange.Select`  and then I had to comment out the whole `ErrFileClose:`  This then stopped the vb error and the error saying I had a duplicate file open.